# Using cloth simulations to model a realistic Snickers wrapper?

Tags: modeling

I am just getting started with blender and would like to model a Snickers wrapper incl. UVs. The basic shape is no problem, but what's the best strategy to get a realistic plastic foil look with all the creases and imperfections?

[image]

I tried the cloth simulation with a bit of pressure, but that's more on the side of a potato chips bag rather than a bar wrapper. Would sculpt mode be a better approach? Or something else?

I am basically after something like this:

[image]

Any tips would be much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Lukas

Comment: Hello, you have better chances of getting a relevant answer if you use a detailed title for your question. Cheers

Comment: thanks for the hint @Gorgious

Comment: i would try using cloth with shrinking factor

Comment: Or perhaps put a candy inside, set it to collision, and then use negative pressure. Probably fairly realistic that way, but maybe delete the candy afterward.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: But the candy won't be destroyed if he uses soft low pressure.... ;)

Comment: @Chris eh, the wha..? Oh, I meant manually delete it afterwards.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: Damn. I misunderstood you. I thought you were joking and meant that the candy would be destroyed by the pressure. My fault. sorry.

Comment: @Chris it’s alright. Certainly not worth a damn, anyway.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard that sounds like a good approach. Would you know a good starting point for the cloth properties to get that plastic foil behaviour? I tried shrinking factor, but that seems to only mess up the mesh.

Comment: @Lukaszzz nah, not at current. Actually, looking at a candy wrapper since then, I’m wondering if it’s actually wrinkled because of vacuum-ness, or actually because the way it’s folded. Sewing might be a better option.

Comment: Sewing…did not know that feature. definitely worth a try. Agree, I think it's more the welding and pressing of the ends that creates the wrinkles. Thanks @ZargulTheWizard